# What is the difference between \NewDocumentCommand and \DeclareDocumentCommand?

Tags: latex3, xparse

These commands are part of the LaTeX3 Project `xparse`package. This question is to satisfy curiosity…

From `xparse` documentation released on 25 Nov 2014:

> `\DeclareDocumentCommand` will always create the new definition, irrespective of any existing  with the same name.
>
> `\NewDocumentCommand` will issue an error if  has already been defined.

Is this the equivalent of `\def` and `\newcommand`?

In what situation would I need this?

Comment: No but the equivalent of `\long\def` and `\newcommand` ;-)

Comment: @touhami Just to clarify for future reference: `\long\def` being just a `\def` that accepts `\par` tokens (both explicit and implicit paragraphs) in its input...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is this the equivalent of `\def` and `\newcommand`?

Not quite: `\DeclareDocumentCommand` has the same syntax as `\NewDocumentCommand`, unlike `\def` with respect to `\newcommand`. But the documentation seems clear about it: with `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, there is *no* check that the command name you give as argument already has a definition.

Don't forget there's also `\RenewDocumentCommand`.

> In what situation would I need this?

I know a few ones, but I usually recommend using `\NewDocumentCommand`. Don't use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. I hope the team will also provide `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

What's the usage of `\DeclareDocumentCommand`? Every time you have to do `\let\foo\relax` and `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{...}`, then it's time to `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. If you don't know what I mean, then use `\NewDocumentCommand` and live happier.